# Can I make VS code warn me of unnecessary null-forgiving operator usages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, compiler-warnings, null-forgiving-operator

If I use a nullable value in a non-nullable context, VS code warns me with `[CS8603] Possible null reference return`.

Example: `private object Foo(Func<object?> foo) { return foo(); }` (VS code underlines `foo()`)

It can be resolved e.g. by adding the null-forgiving operator (to `foo()` in that example).

---

Is there a way to make VS code warn in the inverse case, i.e. if I use a null-forgiving operator in a non-nullable context?

Example: `private object Foo(Func<object> foo) { return foo()!; }` (VS code should underline `foo()!`)

Comment: related issue tickets: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13784 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8453. I don't know why they closed as "completed" :/